# How do I get GitHub Actions to install TA-Lib in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, github, pytest, github-actions, ta-lib

My test suites is running on ubuntu-latest (20.04) has TA-Lib as one of its dependencies.

Is there a way get GitHub Actions to install them before running my tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get ta-lib installed using the following run command.

```yaml
 - run: |
     wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
     tar xvfz ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
     cd ta-lib
     ./configure
     make
     sudo make install
```